# How to send SMS across avd instances?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am trying to send text messages from one instance of android emulator to another by using port number as phone number but it doesn't work. I followed the steps [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#calling) but still not working. Is this method deprecated or is there another way to do it?

Note: I tried to do it on two different machines (a windows machine and a linux machine) using the default messaging app but it didn't work.

Comment: Still works for me. Your last sentence is a little ambiguous, though. Are you running both AVDs on the same machine? Or do you mean that you're running one on a Windows machine, and another on a Linux box?

Comment: @MikeM. Both on the same machine: Android 12.0 & Android Studio 2021.1.1

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure. I tested with lower Android versions, but it does still work between AVDs in general: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEsFy.png. That was sent from the AVD on port 5556, and was addressed simply to 5554. I'll spin up version 12 here in a bit, to see if there's something particular to that.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it might be a problem with the version 12 emulators. R (API level 30) and below all still work for me, but none work with S (API level 31). You could [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new), if you'd like. Personally, I'd probably just use a lower version, at least for now. I don't think S introduces any (major) changes in SMS handling.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you so much. I will use a lower Android version. Thank you